# How to disable a button when input has invalid value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to disable a button, depending if the `OptionsDisplayValue` has some text in it (thus meets the required dependency)

The below doesn't appear to work, and I am not entirely sure why. As when I write `{{AddAttribute.OptionsDisplayValue.$invalid}}` it is returning true.

So I would have thought `ng-disabled="true"` would have worked.

```
<html ng-app>    
    <body>
        <form id="AddAttribute" name="AddAttribute">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
              placeholder="Display Name" required="required" 
              ng-model="OptionsDisplayValue" 
              id="OptionsDisplayValue" name="OptionsDisplayValue" />

            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" 
              id="AddOption" name="AddOption" 
              ng-model="AddOption" 
              ng-disable="AddAttribute.OptionsDisplayValue.$invalid" />

            {{AddAttribute.OptionsDisplayValue.$invalid}}
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am guessing my understanding of how ng-disabled works is miss informed. I have used the checkbox example from the ngDisabled docs, and that appears to work.

How would I go about using the validity of the input as the disabling factor?

Comment: @Default Thanks, I am so blind.

Comment: No problem! Certainly an easy mistake to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is using `ng-disable`, which is a misspelling of the actual directive `ng-disabled`.

Answer (score 3):

Use have missed to add `d` at the end from `disable`

It should be `ng-disabled` instead of `ng-disable`

**Markpup**

```
ng-disabled="AddAttribute.OptionsDisplayValue.$invalid"
```